# A quiz question in elementary number theory about division by polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question was asked in my number theory quiz, but I am unable to solve it.

> Let $a, b, n$ be positive integers such that $n$ divides $a^n -b^n $. Prove that $n$ also divides $ \dfrac{a^n -b^n}{a-b}$.

I started by writing $ a^n -b^n  = (a-b) ( a^{n-1} +... + b^{n-1} ) \equiv 0 \mod n $ . But I don't understand what can I do from it and which result should be used.

Can you please help.

Thank you!!

Comment: You can look up 'Lifting the exponent lemma'.